# Mediawiki error: File upload not working

Tags: file-upload, mediawiki, mediawiki-api, filelock

I've installed Mediawiki v1.24.1 on my server which is running RHEL7. 
I've installed it under /var/www/foohelp/wiki. However, when I try to upload a file, I get the following error:

```
[f3eae72a] /foohelp/wiki/index.php/Special:Upload Exception from line 1871 of /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/filerepo/file/LocalFile.php: Could not acquire lock for 'User-default.png.'
Backtrace:
#0 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/filerepo/file/LocalFile.php(1174): LocalFile->lock()
#1 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/upload/UploadBase.php(738): LocalFile->upload(string, string, string, integer, array, boolean, User)
#2 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/specials/SpecialUpload.php(467): UploadBase->performUpload(string, string, boolean, User)
#3 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/specials/SpecialUpload.php(186): SpecialUpload->processUpload()
#4 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/specialpage/SpecialPage.php(363): SpecialUpload->execute(NULL)
#5 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/specialpage/SpecialPageFactory.php(584): SpecialPage->run(NULL)
#6 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/MediaWiki.php(275): SpecialPageFactory::executePath(Title, RequestContext)
#7 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/MediaWiki.php(584): MediaWiki->performRequest()
#8 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/includes/MediaWiki.php(435): MediaWiki->main()
#9 /var/www/foohelp/mediawiki-1.24.1/index.php(46): MediaWiki->run()
#10 {main}
```

If I edit /includes/filebackend/FileBackendGroup.php 
and modify LockManager to

```
'lockManager' => 'fsLockManager',
```

and modify permissions as follows:

```
chown -R apache:apache images/
chown -R 755 images/
```

I get the following error:

```
(Could not create directory "mwstore://local-backend/local-public)
```

I've tried most of the forums and there is no solution that seems to fix my problem. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Stack Overflow is a site for programming and development questions. This question appears to be off-topic because it is not about programming or development. See [What topics can I ask about here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) in the Help Center. Perhaps [Super User](http://superuser.com/) or [Webmaster Stack Exchange](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask. Also see [Where do I post questions about Dev Ops?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/134306).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to set tmp directory:

```
$wgTmpDirectory = "/var/www/tmp/";
```

And grant rights:

```
chown -R apache:apache tmp/
chown -R 755 tmp/
```

Also try to add global vars:

```
putenv("TMP=/var/www/tmp/");
putenv("HOME=/var/www");
```

And if you use imagemagick:

```
$wgImageMagickTempDir = "/var/www/tmp/";
```

Comment: try to increase memory limit in php.ini